# cant find my main error, debugging at java

Tags: java, debugging

so I'm running a program in java and I can't really find the main error
this is my code:

```
public class Main

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myCheck = 50.00;
        double yourCheck = 19.95;
        double fiinalRATE = 0.15;
        System.out.println("Tips are");
        calcTip(myCheck);
        calcTip(yourCheck);
        public void calcTip(double bill);
        {
        tip = bill * fiinalRATE;
        System.out.println("The tip should be at least " + tip);
    }
}
```

and this is the error that I'm getting I think its the header but I don't really know what to put I'm kinda new at java though
[image]

Comment: You need to define your method calcTip on the class level next to your main method, not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a method inside another method. So the compiler gets crazy :)
Just move you calcTip() function outside main() function (after closing curly bracket of main() or before declaration of main()).

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double myCheck = 50.00;
        double yourCheck = 19.95;
        double fiinalRATE = 0.15;
        System.out.println("Tips are");
        calcTip(myCheck);
        calcTip(yourCheck);
    }

    public static void calcTip(double bill) {
        // fiinalRate must be declared as parameter of calcTip()
        // or as static field in Main class,
        // otherwise the code doesn't compile.
        double tip = bill * fiinalRATE;
        System.out.println("The tip should be at least " + tip);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't compile since `fiinalRATE` is not known inside of  `calcTip`

Comment: @f1sh you're right, as well as Gal Fudim who suggested edition with 'static' key-word for caclTip(). I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare function inside function. You have to pull function out from main() to the Main.class